# how to add a "get all" method using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm wanting to add a "get all" items method in my class. with lineCollection I can see the (.find(), .findall(), .findindex() ) but I don't think this is what I'm needing? Any help?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SportsStore.Domain.Entities
{
    public class Cart
    {
        private readonly List<CartLine> lineCollection = new List<CartLine>();

        public IEnumerable<CartLine> Lines
        {
            get { return lineCollection; }
        }

        public void AddItem(Product product, int quantity)
        {
            CartLine line = lineCollection
                .Where(p => p.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (line == null)
            {
                lineCollection.Add(new CartLine {Product = product, Quantity = quantity});
            }
            else
            {
                line.Quantity += quantity;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveLine(Product product)
        {
            lineCollection.RemoveAll(l => l.Product.ProductID == product.ProductID);
        }

        public decimal ComputeTotalValue()
        {
            return lineCollection.Sum(e => e.Product.Price*e.Quantity);
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            lineCollection.Clear();
        }

    }

    public class CartLine
    {
        public Product Product { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lineCollection is already a list. Just return List to get all the elements. If you want to do something with those elements, you can use a foreach loop. If you need to convert an IQueryable to a List, use .ToList()